# Can't add a new public key via SSH (GITHUB)

Tags: github, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

I am trying to create a new public key via SSH on GitHub.

**> code > SSH > copy > add new public key**

The next window is SSH keys / Add new.

I type in a title, then copy and paste the previously copied text. Then here is the problem.

**The copied text does not begin with SSH-RSA OR ECDSA OR SSH-ED OR SK-ECDSA OR SH-SSH which is required to add the SSH key. The only text I can copy from the SSH tab is very short and beginning with git@github.com...etc **

The error message I get having clicked **add SSH key** - Key is invalid. You must supply a key in OpenSSH public key format

Any help appreciated.

Not sure how to overcome the problem as my colleagues accounts all display SSH-RSA OR ECDSA OR SSH-ED OR SK-ECDSA OR SH-SSH text.

Comment: Hello, This is more of a programming forum, your question is not exactly appropriate. I invite you to look at github's documentation about that https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

Comment: The error message seems clear enough. Does the copied text start with that? You haven't told us what public key you are pasting. What do you expect us to do about it, other than tell you to use the correct public key, anyway??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message indicates you should paste your public key with type of key as prefix.
For example, let's say the hash of your public key is AAAA.......AAIK0 it should be prefixed by ssh-rsa AAAA.......AAIK0 if your key is rsa or ssh-ed25519 AAAA.......AAIK0 if it is an ed25519 key.

Comment: Where should i find my public key?

Comment: in Github you have a link "generating SSH keys", please check this link (https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent), once done you will have your public key and that's this one you need to paste in your github profile. Github will not generate a key for you you need to do it n your own